# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Controller#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Railsapp which is a online shop for prefab garden houses. The process I'm trying to create is `index>show>send inquiry>accept/decline quotation>purchase house`. So when the user is on the show page he sees a button to send an inquiry (UserMailer is triggered and sends an email to user as confirmation and an email to admin to make quotation). The admin (read: business owner) will have a link in his email that sends him to the inquiry show page (which is shows a picture of the house with price, delivery cost and total). Admin clicks edit to edit the the delivery cost. When he clicks submit the inquiry record is updated and the user will receive an email that the quotation is ready with a link to the inquiry show page. For him he will see an accept and decline button. I'm stuck at this point.

I wrote new routes and controller actions to take care of the accept or decline. This will either give the inquiry record respectively the state `quotation accepted` or `quotation declined`.

I have a Railsapp which is a online shop for prefab garden houses. The process I'm trying to create is `index>show>send inquiry>accept/decline quotation>purchase house`. So when the user is on the show page he sees a button to send an inquiry (UserMailer is triggered and sends an email to user as confirmation and an email to admin to make quotation). The admin (read: business owner) will have a link in his email that sends him to the inquiry show page (which is shows a picture of the house with price, delivery cost and total). Admin clicks edit to edit the the delivery cost. When he clicks submit the inquiry record is updated and the user will receive an email that the quotation is ready with a link to the inquiry show page. For him he will see an accept and decline button. I'm stuck at this point.

I wrote new routes and controller actions to take care of the accept or decline. This will either give the inquiry record respectively the state `quotation accepted` or `quotation declined`.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount Attachinary::Engine => "/attachinary"
  devise_for :users
  root 'houses#index'
  resources :houses do
    resources :inquiries
    put 'inquiries/:id', to: 'inquiries#accept', as: :accept
    put 'inquiries/:id', to: 'inquiries#decline', as: :decline
  end
  resources :orders, only: [:show, :create] do
    resources :payments, only: [:new, :create]
  end
end
```

and the controller:

```
class InquiriesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_house
  before_action :set_inquiry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :accept]

  def show
  end

  def new
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new
    authorize @inquiry
  end

  def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(inquiry_params)
    authorize @inquiry
    @inquiry.state = 'pending'
    @inquiry.house = @house
    @admin = User.find_by(admin: true)
    if @inquiry.save
      UserMailer.inquiry(@inquiry, @house).deliver_now
      AdminMailer.lead(@inquiry, @admin, @house).deliver_now
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @inquiry.update(inquiry_params)
      @inquiry.update(state: 'quotation created')
      UserMailer.quotation(@inquiry, @house).deliver_now
      redirect_to house_inquiry_path
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def accept
    @inquiry.state = "quotation accepted"
    redirect_to house_path(@house)
  end

  def decline
    @inquiry.state = "quotation declined"
    redirect_to house_path(@house)
  end

  private

  def set_house
    @house = House.find(params[:house_id])
  end

  def set_inquiry
    @inquiry = Inquiry.find(params[:id])
    authorize @inquiry
  end

  def inquiry_params
    params.require(:inquiry).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :region, :comment)
  end
end
```

When I click now on the accept button I get a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in InquiriesController#show` error with explanation `Couldn't find House with 'id'=15`. The url is on `http://localhost:3000/houses/15/inquiries/15` which is not the house_path, but the house_inquiry_path and it has taken the inquiry as the house id at the same time. The house_path, which I want the user to be redirected to is this:  `http://localhost:3000/houses/2`.

Comment: can you also share the code for your views, especially where your accept button is located?

Comment: Do you have the `house_id` in params? as `set_house` is called for every action

Comment: First, don't use the dry concept in such cases. set the house variable like you would normally do (find the house id) and add it before you set the     inquiry = Inquiry.new(inquiry_params). Also, your inquiry_params don't accept a house_id, which should be the case, unless i misunderstood what your trying to do. Because you are using nested resources, you have to build the inquiry also from the house and not the other way around: inquiry = house.inqueries.create(inquery_params) and then if inquiry.save do whatever you want to do. If you can't fix it, post your form if possible!

Comment: Notice that you have to add the @ tag of course, stackoverflow just doesn't allow to use it in the comment section obviously.